# Add custom HTML in New Tab on Product Page - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to Add a new tab on single product page. My below codes works well:-

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
}
```

I want to insert some html data in the 'title' =>

For example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
    function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    // Adds the new tab
        $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => __( 'Additional Information <img src="'.$image.'"/>', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority'  => 50,
            'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
        );
    }
```

The above codes outputs the full html source instead the image.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you look into `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\tabs.php` line number 37 `esc_html()` is responsible for printing HTML as a text in tab title. So I would suggest you to add the image using css. _There might be a way to achieve this using PHP only but that I don't know_

Comment: Hi @RaunakGupta Thanks for comments. I have the dynamic data which can not be added in css. Like <img src="" title="" alt=""/>

Comment: You can also have dynamic css by using `wp_head` action

Answer (score 1):

Here you can:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
 function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
 // Adds the new tab
 $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);
}


function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
 // The new tab content
 echo '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thanks for response. but i do not need it in the content. I need it on the Tab Title.

Comment: we can do this with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old, but I have had the same problem. You can solve it with a custom filter for the tab title.

So you have this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional Information <img src="'.$image.'"/>', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
}
```

Now you got a tab called "desc_tab". The problem is that WooCommerce does not escape the HTML part of it, but you can use a filter, so WooCommerce translates the tab title to HTML:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_desc_tab_tab_title', 'decode_html_tab', 10, 2);
function decode_html_tab($title, $key) {
    $title = html_entity_decode( $title, ENT_QUOTES );
    return $title;
}
```

You have to pay attention to the title of the filter. It is a composition of 'woocommerce_' + the tab title + '_tab_title'.

I hope